# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Citing from **[The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)**:

---

> **5. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?**
>
> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is about. Every word counts!
>
> Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:
>
> - the tagline
> - the motto
> - the blurb under the logo
> - a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
> - perhaps eventually the domain name [in some form](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)
>
> (Due to a variety of [practical difficulties with domain names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), we prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain their `topic.stackexchange.com` names indefinitely.)
>
> Naming is hard — really hard. But if you can come up with a sensible elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.
>
> For more detail see: [Stack Exchange Naming for Dummies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)

---

As our beta is now over 670 days old and [doesn't look that bad](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7080/physical-fitness), why not start getting some ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ideas for a fitness tagline?](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/147/ideas-for-a-fitness-tagline)

Comment: I'd keep this version around and use the old version for inspiration only

Comment: Rep for Rep(s). One rep after the other.</bad pun>

Answer (score 2):

Exercise Exchange

Slack Exchange (slack = lazy? tenuous at least)

Work out your workouts

Exercise Smarter

Pre-workout answers

Although the cynic in me might just say: "Eat better/smarter, drink more water, go exercise more, 5x5 Stronglifts and DOMS are normal" in a elevator

edit:

What about just "Fit" as our tagline?

"There are lot of misconceptions about what it takes to be 'Fit' and SE's 'Fit' site aims to solve that."

edit: FitnesSE?

Comment: "Gain 30 lbs of muscle in just one month with just these 5974 weird tricks."

Answer (score 0):

Since a lot of people originally come from 'the big three', why not make fun of the common prejudice?

*End your Slack on Fitness.Stack*
  obvious pun

*From Fatness.Slack to Fitness.Stack*
  I like puns

*From Visual Fatness to Physical Fitness*
  originally *Virtual Fatness*, my dictionary told me that *physical* can be translated as *real* so virtual would be the opposite, but visual sounded catchier.